# Simultaneous creation of Rails resource and nested resources fails, but not systematically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Ok sorry for the weird title, it's hard to sumarize.

I have this basic setup

```
class Release
  has_many :batches
end
```

and

```
class Batch
  belongs_to :release
end
```

and the `batches` database table has a non-nil constrain on the foreign-key `release_id`.

I have a simple form that creates both a release and its first batch in one go :

```
form_for @release do |f|
  ...
  f.fields_for :batches do |ff|
    ...
  end
end
```

That works perfectly locally as well as most times in production.

In some rare occasions, the creation fails because the batch's `release_id` is `nil` at the time of creation. This means that sometimes it is set, sometimes it is not. Without digging into ActiveRecord, my best guess is that this is a question of timing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna try this solution : https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4599-validations-on-nested-attributes-fail-on-nil-foreign-key-on-object-creation